# How to fire a JavaScript function in Java class?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP and a Java class that work with each other.

I have a boolean variable in my Java class.
I want to check it all the time with AJAX, if its value has changed to true. A JavaScript alert shows a message.

In JSF, there is something like this :

```
<h:outputScript rendered="#{categoryBean.showCategoryNameAlert}">
    alert("CategoryName already exist!");
 </h:outputScript>
```

but I don't know how to do it in JSP?

Comment: See [Using AJAX with JSF](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-ajax.htm#GKIOW)

Comment: tnx, but I don't want JSF , I want to do this in JSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the following example.

Front-end part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get('/backEnd',function(responseText) {
           if(responseText == 'true') {
              alert("Variable has been set");
           }                
        });
    },1000);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Back-end part:

```
@WebServlet(name = "checkerServlet", urlPatterns = { "/backEnd" })
public class CheckerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private YourClass yourClass;

    @Override
    public void init() {
       yourClass = new YourClass();
    }       

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {        
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        if(yourClass.getBooleanValue) {
           writer.write("true");                
        } else {
           writer.write("false");
        }

        writer.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         doGet(request, response);
    }   
}
```

Example of a class with a `boolean` variable -

```
public class YourClass {
   private static boolean booleanValue = false;

   public void setBooleanValue() {
      booleanValue = true;
   }

   public void resetBooleanValue() {
      booleanValue = false;
   }

   public boolean getBooleanValue() {
      return booleanValue;
   }   
   ...
}
```

---

If you are not using a servlet, you can use this call:

```
<%@ page import="fullpackagename.YourClass" %>
<jsp:useBean id="yourClass" scope="request" class="fullpackagename.YourClass" />

<% 
   YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
   // check your variable here
%>
```

Add it to the presentation layer.

Code for auto-refreshing:

`<%response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 1); %>`

Answer (score 0):

you need a servlet that listen on a specific url. give it "/check".

in servlet :

```
if(category.categoryName != null) // or any thing you want
    out.write("true");  // out is response outputstream
```

in jsp : a ajax request that request for "/check" all the time and alert if see true.

Comment: thanks , but I have a JSP and a Java class , there is no servlert